# .cvspass file generation to configure hudson tool

Tags: jenkins, hudson, cvs, hudson-plugins

Please help me in generating the .cvspass file to configure hudson tool .

Answer (score 9):

this is simple, run form commandline

```
cvs -d :pserver:login:password@host:/dir/ login
```

This create `.cvspass` for you.

OR

simple paste to hudson `CVSROOT` variable this:

```
:pserver:login:password@host:/dir/
```

This is with password, so you dont need to create `.cvspass`

Answer (score 1):

`.cvspass` is only created using a windows native compiled CVS.

Confirm using `cvs -version` that you are not using `cvs (CVSNT)`. 
`CVSNT` does not create `.cvspass`.